# Unity Raycast has inconsistent behavior. Sometimes it collides with the collider it starts in and sometimes not

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

[image: Problem I have]

The text in this image pretty much explains everything.

This is the code that creates the rays. You may ignore `Debug.DrawRay()`.

```
RaycastHit hitInfo;
RaycastHit wall;
RaycastHit backFace;

if(Physics.Raycast(barrelEnd.transform.position, barrelEnd.transform.forward, out hitInfo)) {
            
            Debug.DrawRay(barrelEnd.transform.position, barrelEnd.transform.forward*5, Color.green, 5f, false);
            Instantiate(rayOneHit, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.identity);
            Enemy target = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            
            if(target != null) {

                if(Physics.Raycast(hitInfo.point, barrelEnd.transform.forward, out wall)) {
                    
                    Debug.DrawRay(hitInfo.point, (hitInfo.point - barrelEnd.transform.position)*2, Color.blue, 5f, false);
                    Instantiate(rayTwoHit, wall.point, Quaternion.identity);

                    if(Physics.Raycast(wall.point, ((hitInfo.point - wall.point)/Vector3.Distance(hitInfo.point,wall.point)), out backFace)) { 
                        
                        Debug.DrawRay(wall.point, (hitInfo.point - wall.point)*10, Color.red, 5f, false);
                        
                        Vector3 hitLocation = new Vector3(backFace.point.x, backFace.point.y, backFace.point.z);
                        Instantiate(hitPoint, hitLocation, Quaternion.identity);
                    }
                }
                target.dealDamage(damage);
            }
            
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, aim.transform.position);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitInfo.point);
        }
```

This is all inside of a function `Shoot()` which is called as follows:

```
void Update() {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
```

Full code if needed:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Transform aim;
    [SerializeField] LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float damage = 30f;
    public Transform barrelEnd;
    public Transform crosshair;
    public Light muzzleFlash;
    public Object hitPoint;
    public Object rayOneHit;
    public Object rayTwoHit;
    public LayerMask enemyLayer;
    
    //public Light muzzleFlashSelf;
    
   // public GameObject projectile;
    public float force = 100f;

    void Start() {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        muzzleFlash.enabled = false;
        //muzzleFlashSelf.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot() {
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        RaycastHit wall;
        RaycastHit backFace;

        StartCoroutine(DrawLine());
        StartCoroutine(Flash());

        if(Physics.Raycast(barrelEnd.transform.position, barrelEnd.transform.forward, out hitInfo)) {
            
            Debug.DrawRay(barrelEnd.transform.position, barrelEnd.transform.forward*5, Color.green, 5f, false);
            Instantiate(rayOneHit, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.identity);
            Enemy target = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            
            if(target != null) {

                if(Physics.Raycast(hitInfo.point, barrelEnd.transform.forward, out wall)) {
                    
                    Debug.DrawRay(hitInfo.point, (hitInfo.point - barrelEnd.transform.position)*2, Color.blue, 5f, false);
                    Instantiate(rayTwoHit, wall.point, Quaternion.identity);

                    if(Physics.Raycast(wall.point, ((hitInfo.point - wall.point)/Vector3.Distance(hitInfo.point,wall.point)), out backFace)) { 
                        
                        Debug.DrawRay(wall.point, (hitInfo.point - wall.point)*10, Color.red, 5f, false);
                        
                        Vector3 hitLocation = new Vector3(backFace.point.x, backFace.point.y, backFace.point.z);
                        Instantiate(hitPoint, hitLocation, Quaternion.identity);
                    }
                }
                target.dealDamage(damage);
            }
            
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, aim.transform.position);
            lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitInfo.point);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DrawLine() {
        lineRenderer.enabled = true;
        float t = 0;
        float time = 0.01f;

        Vector3 orig = lineRenderer.GetPosition(0);
        Vector3 orig2 = lineRenderer.GetPosition(1);

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, orig);

        for (; t < time; t += Time.deltaTime) {
            yield return null;
        }

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, orig2);
        lineRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    IEnumerator Flash() {
        float t = 0;
        float time = 0.1f;
        muzzleFlash.enabled = true;
        //muzzleFlashSelf.enabled = true;

        for (; t < time; t += Time.deltaTime) {
            yield return null;
        }

        muzzleFlash.enabled = false;
        //muzzleFlashSelf.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I've tried to start the 2nd raycast slightly further inside of the enemy, because I thought maybe it is hitting the very edge of the collider but this changed nothing. I've also tried to use `~enemyMask` to exclude the enemy, but this just made the second ray not fire at all.